# Is there any Go lib that can parse InfluxDB's Line Protocol?

Tags: go, line, protocols, influxdb

Hopefully, I didn't just simply miss any official lib, cuz InfluxDB is written by Go. I just wasn't able to find a Go lib that can handle the Line Protocol.

Since we are using InfluxDB's Subscription feature, and it delivers the data via Line Protocol. There isn't much other simple options either.

Answer (score 0):

K. Actually found the answer within InfluxDB's source code.

```golang
import  "github.com/influxdata/influxdb/models"

func Parse(body []byte) {
    points, err := models.ParsePointsWithPrecision(body, time.Now().UTC(), "n")
    ...
}
```